# Logistic mixed model with 33% chance

Tags: r, logistic, anova, mixed-model

I have an experiment in which subject need to answer a discrimination task with 3 options (chance = 33%). Because the number of trials with this task varies between subjects I wanted to do mixed model paradigm.

The theory was to built 2 models in `R`:
one with 1 as intercept (meaning we don't define it) and one define as 33%, and compare the models with anova.
(I now that intercept of 0 is 50%, how do I define 33%?)

I couldn't define the second model.

Here is what I was trying to so (the second is just a blub and doesnt work)

`m1<-glmer(success ~1+(1|subject),data=m1_m2_data,family=binomial) # the intercept is undefined` 
`m2<-glmer((success) ~0.33 +(1|subject),data=m1_m2_data,family=binomial) #how do define chance as 33%?`

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Is your response variable categorical with three categories (e.g. dog, cat, alligator)?

Comment: It is 3 sounds with different pitches. so it is not quite categorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try working with an offset, i.e.,

```
m2 <- glmer(success ~ 0 + offset(rep(qlogis(0.33), len = subject)) + 
                (1 | subject), data = m1_m2_data, 
            family = binomial())
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.

I just changed the "length= subject" to "length= nrow(m1_m2_data)" because this is the number of observation, am I right?
Apart from this it works!

Comment: Yes, that is correct.